# AppConfig file not found in bin directory

Tags: c#, file-structure

I have a `App.Config` file that users can go to and set some settings to run the program.
But when I go to bin\release folder of my program to copy and give them the exe,DLLs, etc I can't find the `App.Config` file.
What should I do?
It is a ConsoleApp.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

your `App.Config` willbe converted to `ApplicationName.exe.config`

so if your application name is `SampleApplication.exe` then you need to check for the following filename

`SampleApplication.exe.config`.

FROM MSDN :  [`App.Config`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx)

> When you develop in Visual Studio, place the source configuration file
>   for your app in the project directory and set its Copy To Output
>   Directory property to Copy always or Copy if newer. The name of the
>   configuration file is the name of the app with a .config extension.
>   For example, an app called **myApp.exe** should have a source
>   configuration file called **myApp.exe.config**.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Ok I found it now, I was thinking it should be an XML file.

Comment: yes it is a xml file but it will not have `xml` as an extension.

Answer (score 7):

Is the App.config file set to copy on build? If you right-click on the App.config in VS, and go to Properties, it should be set to 'Content' and 'Copy Always'/'Copy if newer'.

Here is a screenshot of the Properties screen:

[image: The App.config properties to check:]