# VB.NET: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings is returning none of the options defined app.config

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Here is my App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration> 
  <connectionStrings> 
    <clear/>
    <add name="con1" connectionString="..." /> 
    <add name="con2" connectionString="..."/> 
    <add name="con3" connectionString="..."/> 
    <add name="con4" connectionString="..." /> 
    <add name="con5" connectionString="..."/> 
  </connectionStrings> 
  <appSettings> 
    <add key="S...
  ...
</configuration>
```

I have a breakpoint that I'm hitting right before I try to create a database connection, and in the `Immediate Window`, I run this:

```
?ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item(0).ConnectionString
```

but it returns this:

```
"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

Which isn't defined anywhere. (All my connections are remote MSSQLServer instances)

doing `?ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(1)` gives an Index out of range error, so there is only one entry in my connection strings settings object :-(

What's going on? this feels crazy.

I'm using VS2013, VB.NET, and .NET 4.0

Comment: Is this an asp.net project? If so, then I don't think it will use app.config. Does your project have a web.config file?

Comment: it's a windows application project. There is only the app.config

Comment: It's not using your app.config file, and therefore picking up a connection string that's probably defined in machine.config.  When you build a Windows app, the build process will convert app.config into a file "MyApp.exe.config" in the same directory as your executable "MyApp.exe".  Check that this file exists, and look at its contents.

Comment: something to check...once an app gets compiled and sent to is folder (under bin\debug or bin\release), there should be a file names <appexename>.config. open that with notepad, and ensure that it contains the right settings.

Comment: I looked in bin/ but didn't see debug or release, but I did see the program.exe, but no config. I found debug and release in obj/, but neither debug nor release contain a program.exe.config :-(

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296098/appconfig-file-not-found-in-bin-directory

Comment: That helps. I also found out that when I went to "Add an existing file" to my unit test project, it copied the file to the unit test directory... so I DID have two App.Configs

Comment: now, actually my tests don't pass, because it things that my configuration is empty. just as it did before. Maybe that's why I originally added App.config to my test project. Is there a way around this?

Comment: fixed it! had to make sure App.Config was copied to the output directory :-)